# How can I configure CloudFront so it costs me a bit less?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a very static site, basically HTML and some Javascript on S3. I serve this through Cloudfront. My usage has gone up a bit plus one of my Javascript files is pretty large.

So what can I do to cut down the costs of serving those files? they need have very good uptime as it has thousands of active users all over the world.

This is the usage for yesterday:

[image]

Looking at other questions about this it seems like changing headers can help but I thought I already had caching enabled. This is what `curl` returns if I get one of those files:

```
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 200
< content-type: text/html
< content-length: 2246
< date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 20:28:47 GMT
< last-modified: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 15:21:11 GMT
< x-amz-version-id: some string
< etag: "83df2032241b5be7b4c337f0857095fc"
< server: AmazonS3
< x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 somestring.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: some string
< x-amz-cf-id: some string
```

This is what the cache is configured as on CloudFront:

[image]

This is what S3 says when I use `curl` to query the file:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: some string
< x-amz-request-id: some string
< Date: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 20:27:22 GMT
< x-amz-replication-status: COMPLETED
< Last-Modified: Fri, 03 Apr 2020 15:21:11 GMT
< ETag: "83df2032241b5be7b4c337f0857095fc"
< x-amz-version-id: some string
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 2246
< Server: AmazonS3
```

So what can I do? I don't often update the files and when I do I don't mind if it takes a day or two for the change to propagate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to reduce CloudFront costs, then it's worth reviewing how it is charged:

- **Regional Data Transfer Out to Internet (per GB):** From $0.085 to $0.170 (depending upon location of your users)
- **Regional Data Transfer Out to Origin (per GB):** From $0.020 to $0.160 (data going back to your application)
- **Request Pricing for All HTTP Methods (per 10,000):** From $0.0075 to $0.0090

Compare that to **Amazon S3**:

- **GET Requests:** $0.0004 per 1000
- **Data Transfer:** $0.09 per GB (Also applies for traffic coming from Amazon EC2 instances)

Therefore, some options for you to save money are:

- **Choose a lower Price Class** that restricts which regions send traffic "out". For example, `Price Class 100` only sends traffic from USA and Europe, which has lower Data Transfer costs. This will reduce Data Transfer costs for other locations, but will give them a lower quality of service (higher latency).
- **Stop using CloudFront** and serve content directly from S3 and EC2.  This will save a bit on requests (about half the price), but Data Transfer would be a similar cost to Price Class 100.
- **Increase the caching duration** for your objects. However, the report is showing 99.9%+ hit rates, so this won't help much.
- Configure the objects to persist longer in user's browsers so less requests are made. However, this only works for "repeat traffic" and might not help much. It depends on app usage. (I'm not familiar with this part. It might not work in conjunction with CloudFront. Hopefully other readers can comment.)

Typically, mosts costs are related to the volume of traffic. If you app is popular, those Data Transfer costs will go up.

Take a look at your bills and try to determine which component is leading to most of the costs. Then, it's a trade-off between service to your customers and costs to you. Changing the Price Class might be the best option for now.